# How to get next page of records over 10,000 in Dynamics 365 REST API

Tags: rest, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I am able to query Dynamics 365 API

```
https://<COMPANY-NAME>.dynamics.com/data/Ledgers?$filter=AccountingDate+ge+{0}+and+AccountingDate+lt+{1}
```

Where `{0}` and `{1}` are dates (i.e. `2019-03-15`)

The problem is that Dynamic 365 API has a limit of **10,000 records** returned and there are more than 10,000 records. Is there a parameter to add to the URI that enables me to obtain the next "batch" of records so I can obtain all of them?

I have search with my Google-Fu but I must still be at the grasshopper level because I cannot find anything in Microsoft's Dynamics 365 API reference or on the web that mentions it. I am looking for a REST like solution so I can use this cross platform and not have to depend on an SDK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This referred to as Paging, and is common on most REST APIs

Microsoft Dynamics 365 Web API follows the [odata](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/) standard for paging, and when there are more pages of data to retrieve the *@odata.nextlink* property is included in the response which you can use to create another request to get the next page of information, this can be repeated until the *@odata.nextlink* is null or missing to get to the end of the dataset.

There is more detailed information about API limits in the Microsoft docs under the [Limit](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/), as well as specific samples for [Paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/web-api-query-data-sample#bkmk_filterPagination) for the Dynamics 365 Web API.

Comment: Thank you very much! The link to the odata examples was invaluable as was the Microsoft examples. Just what I was looking for!